# Css contents are not applying in a page when Iam redirecting the page using requestdispatcher in filter

Tags: html, css, jsf, richfaces, servlet-filters

After checking the condition if the condition fails then using request dispatcher iam redirecting it to some other page.It is redirecting to that page but the css is not applying to that page.Why is it so?

```
public class RolePrivilegeFilter implements Filter {
List<String> privilege = null;
private static final String notAuthorizedPath = "/home/notAuthorized.jsf";
@Override
public void destroy() {
log.info("filter finish");
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest sRequest, ServletResponse sResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
String smUser = null;
 try {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) sRequest;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) sResponse;
    HttpSession session = null;
    try {
        request = (HttpServletRequest) sRequest;
        smUser =  request.getHeader(EnvironmentBean.SESSION_ATTR_SM_USER);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    if (rolePrivilege == null || rolePrivilege.isEmpty()) {
    rolePrivilege = new RolePrivilegeBuilderImpl().rolePrivilege("Smtest2");
    privilege filter bean is\t"+rolePrivilege);
    log.debug("After rolePrivilege: " + rolePrivilege);
    if (rolePrivilege != null && rolePrivilege.size() > 0 ) {
    if (session == null) {
        session = request.getSession(true);
    }
    session.setAttribute("privilege", rolePrivilege);

    } else {
             //This is the page iam  redirecting to. 
    System.out.println("role privilege not authorized page");
    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(notAuthorizedPath);
                    rd.forward(request, response);
                    return;
           }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.debug("Error in setting session attribute: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    log.debug("doFilter() finish");
    filterChain.doFilter(sRequest, sResponse);
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
    log.info("filter start");

}
}
```

The problem is iam redirecting to that page but the css to that page is not being applied like background image not getting displayed.Why is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the filter's URL pattern did *also* match the browser's request for that CSS file and thus it has also been blocked by the filter. Apparently you've mapped the filter on a too broad URL pattern like as `/*` or something.

You need to ensure that the filter bypasses all those CSS file requests. If there's no way to change the filter's URL pattern accordingly so that it bypasses CSS file requests, e.g. changing `/*` to `/app/*` so that it only runs on requests in `/app` folder where all restricted resources are, then you need to rewrite the filter's code to add an extra check on the request URI.

Something like this:

```
if (request.getRequestURI().endsWith(".css")) {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
    return;
}
```

This will let all `*.css` requests be passed instead of being blocked.

Comment: Thanks balusC but what is resource handler in the above code.

Comment: The JSF standard one is from the `javax.faces.application` package and the RichFaces one is from `org.richfaces.resource` package. Just let your IDE auto-complete the imports.

Comment: IDE is not showing for import statments its showing create a class resource handler.

Comment: Please verifiy once again if you are really using JSF 2.0 and RichFaces 4.0. Your question was tagged `[jsf-2.0]`, so I assumed JSF 2.0. Those classes don't exist in JSF 1.x and RichFaces 3.x and a different solution needs to be used. But the concrete problem still boils down to that your CSS files are also blocked by that filter and that you need to rewrite your filter to let them pass.

Comment: jsf-api-1.2_12,jsf-facelets-1.1.15,richfaces-api-3.3.3 these are the jars iam using.Sorry when I was tagging selected the first one and it was jsf 2.0. Iam using jsf 1.2 and rich faces 3.3

Comment: Okay, I edited the answer. In the future please be more careful what you tag.

Comment: In request.getRequestURI function I would be getting .jsf since in one bean I have given navigation paths and for page Iam redirecting  the include statements are like this                <link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="${facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/css/common.css"/>
 
<ui:include src="/templates/include/dynamic-css.xhtml" />

Comment: I do not understand your concrete problem at all. Do you understand in any way how basic HTTP, webservers, webbrowsers in general work? JSF is executed in webserver and HTML is executed in webbrowser. Any `<link>` (and `<script>` and `<img>`) references in HTML are by the webbrowser in turn downloaded from the webserver by entirely separate HTTP requests which would in turn invoke any filters on `/*`. Have you in *any way* understood and tried the proposed solution in my answer?

Comment: Thanks balusc got the solution and it is displaying fine.Now all css is getting applied.